# Custom Post Type Causes Error: Warning: call_user_func_array()

Tags: custom-post-types, php, errors

I have a custom post type created called 'missions'. When developing the site on my Dedicated Virtual, I had no problems. But I moved the site to a shared hosting grid server (mt) and now receive this error through out the admin.

> Warning: call_user_func_array()
>   [function.call-user-func-array]: First
>   argument is expected to be a valid
>   callback, 'add_mission' was given in
>   /nfs/c08/h02/mnt/125591/domains/mydomain.org/html/wp-includes/plugin.php
>   on line 395

The only place that 'add_mission' is used in my theme code is in the functions when setting up the post type. Here is the code I have for that.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_mission' );
function create_mission() {
    register_post_type( 'missions',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Missions' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Mission' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Mission' ),
                'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Mission' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'New Mission' ),
                'view' => __( 'View Mission' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View Mission' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Missions' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'No missions found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No missions found in Trash' ),
                'parent' => __( 'Parent Mission' ),
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 4,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            '_edit_link' =>  'post.php?post=%d',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'missions', 'with_front' => true ),
            'supports' => array( 
                        'title',
                        'editor',
                        'author',
                        'thumbnail',
                        'excerpt',
                        'trackbacks',
                        'custom-fields',
                        'comments' ,
                        'page-attributes',
                        'templates' ),
            'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/imgs/icon_posttype.png',
            'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_mission_metaboxes'
        )
    );
}
add_action('admin_init', 'add_mission');
```

**More Info**

I know that the issue is with my theme, as switching to the twentyten theme removes the error.

PHP Version 5.2.14

WordPress 3.1.2

**Question**

Is this a server issue? Or can I fix this through my code?

I've searched google and have been unable to find an instance of this error being thrown from a custom post type in wordpress.

Comment: what's the add action at the bottom doing? It's not required for setting up CPTs, just the setup bit you have running on init.... I believe that is what's throwing the error

Comment: And that seems to have been the problem. It was old code, referencing a different meta box approach I had tried earlier. I wonder why the error wasn't thrown in the DV server. Thank you sir!

Comment: I'm a SE n00b, and cannot figure out how to mark your response as an answer. :(

Comment: I re-posted it as an answer, thank you for reporting back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's the add action at the bottom doing? It's not required for setting up CPTs, just the setup bit you have running on init.... I believe that is what's throwing the error

I have to make it an answer. It was a suggestion, but if it worked for you, I'll make my comment an answer, then you can accept it!